# Access static final variable using reflection

Tags: java, reflection, static

I have a Java class with a static variable

```
package com.mytest
public class MyClass{
    public static final TextClass TEXT_CLASS = new TextClass();
}
```

How can I access the object `TEXT_CLASS` using reflection?

(I have the string `"com.mytest.MyClass.TEXT_CLASS"`. I need to access the object.)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Accessing static fields is done exactly the same way as normal fields, only you don't need to pass any argument to `Field.get()` method (you can pass a null).

Try this:

```
Object getFieldValue(String path) throws Exception {
    int lastDot = path.lastIndexOf(".");
    String className = path.substring(0, lastDot);
    String fieldName = path.substring(lastDot + 1);
    Class myClass = Class.forName(className);
    Field myField = myClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    return myField.get(null);
}
```

Comment: Might want to add a:  myField.setAccessible(true); in there.