# How to have multiple config files for a set of constants to allow for easy switching from one to another?

Tags: java

I need to maintain a file of string & int constants to declare the config parameters for my application. I had them declared as  `static final` constants in a simple java class for good performance. But now I realize that I should also be able to have multiple such configuration files & easily switch from using one config file to another config file. Right now I have the file like this:

```
public final class Config {
    public static final String A1="...";
    public static final String A2="...";
           ...
    public static final String AN="...";

}
```

to use any config param, i just use like this: `Config.A1`

These param are heavily used in application thus I wanted direct access to the fields(rather than through getter methods) with good performance.

But how should I be able to maintain multiple such config files & allow easy switching from one to another ?

Comment: You can use reflection. Here's some reference- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992448/access-static-final-variable-using-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public final class Config {
    public static final String A1;
    public static final String A2;
    ...
    public static final String AN;

    static
    {
        Properties props = new Properties ();
        try
        {
            props.load (new FileInputStream (System.getProperty ("config.file")));
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException (ex);
        }
        A1 = props.getProperty ("A1");
        A2 = props.getProperty ("A2");
        ...
        AN = props.getProperty ("AN");
    }
}
```

Then you can use system property `config.file` to specify what configuration file to use.

Comment: thanks a lot! is there any particular format according to which the parameters must be written inside config.file. Could you point to any links please, that guide about how to write the config.file ?

Comment: @user01 In my example it should be Java Properties file as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29

Answer (score 0):

Use properties files. Store which property file should be used in a System property.

This is an example of how you could do it. You should use a singleton instead of static methods, and you should keep the ResourceBundle loaded instead of loading the properties file every time. This is just an example.

```
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Config {

    //Stores the currently used property file
    private static String route;

    public static String getRoute() {
        return route;
    }

    public static void setRoute(String route) {
        this.route = route;
    }

    //Read a value from a properties file.
    //Mikhail Vladimirov wrote another way of doing it, so this is just an example of another way of doing it.
    private static String fetchTextFrom(String key, String route) {
        String text = null;
        try {
            ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(route);
            text = bundle.getString(key);
        } catch (MissingResourceException mre) {
            text = key;
        }
        return text;
    }

    //Read a value from the current properties file
    public static String fetchText(String key) {
        return fetchTextFrom(key, getRoute());
    }
}
```